# Monitor the changes in table using JavaScript or HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the total price when the count or unit price of the products are changed on the website. I know I should use the `onChange` function, but I have no idea about how to write the JavaScript code.

```
<table id="productTable" class="layui-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th>PART NUMBER</th>
            <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
            <th>QTY(PCS)</th>
            <th>UNIT PRICE (USD)</th>
            <th>AMOUNT(USD)</th>
            <th>OPRATION</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="columns">
        <tr style="display:none">
            <td>1</td>
            <td><input type="hidden"  name="numberList"></td>
            <td><input type="hidden"  name="remarkList"></td>
            <td><input type="hidden"  name="countList"></td>
            <td><input type="hidden"  name="priceList"></td>
            <td><input type="hidden"  name="totalPriceList"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr  th:each="orderProduct:${orderProducts}">
            <td th:text="${orderProducts.indexOf(orderProduct)+1}"></td>
            <td contenteditable="true" >
                <input type="text"  name="numberList"  class="layui-input number" th:value="${orderProduct.number}">
            </td>
            <td contenteditable="true" >
                <input type="text" name="remarkList" class="layui-input remark" th:value="${orderProduct.remark}">
            </td>
            <td id="productCoun" contenteditable="true" >
                <input id="productCount" type="text" name="countList" onchange="update()" class="layui-input count"
                th:value="${orderProduct.count}">
            </td>
            <td id="normalPric" contenteditable="true" >
                <input id="normalPrice" type="text" name="priceList" onchange="update()" class="layui-input price"
                th:value="${orderProduct.price}">
            </td>
            <td id="totalPric" th:text="${orderProduct.price}*${orderProduct.count}">
                <input id="total" type="text" name="totalPriceList" class="layui-input price"
                th:text="${orderProduct.price}*${orderProduct.count}">
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="" class="EditBtn">Edit</a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="delBtn redType" onclick='delColumns(this)'>Del</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I hope that the `totalPrice = count*price` could refresh whenever the user changes one of those values.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily monitor the pointed input fields (`#productCount` and `#normalPrice`) and change the value of `#total` according to it. In the code below, I use the `input` event and I'm not using inline event handlers, but rather the function `addEventListener()` ([know why](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these)).

```js
const productCountInput = document.querySelector('#productCount');
const productPriceInput = document.querySelector('#normalPrice');
const totalPriceInput = document.querySelector('#total');

function updateTotalPrice() {
  totalPriceInput.value = (parseFloat(productCountInput.value) * parseFloat(productPriceInput.value)) || 0;
}

productCountInput.addEventListener('input', updateTotalPrice);
productPriceInput.addEventListener('input', updateTotalPrice);
```

```html
<table id="productTable" class="layui-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>No.</th>
      <th>PART NUMBER</th>
      <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
      <th>QTY(PCS)</th>
      <th>UNIT PRICE (USD)</th>
      <th>AMOUNT(USD)</th>
      <th>OPRATION</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="columns">
    <tr style="display:none">
      <td>1</td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="numberList"></td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="remarkList"></td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="countList"></td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="priceList"></td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="totalPriceList"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr th:each="orderProduct:${orderProducts}">
      <td th:text="${orderProducts.indexOf(orderProduct)+1}"></td>
      <td contenteditable="true">
        <input type="text" name="numberList" class="layui-input number" th:value="${orderProduct.number}">
      </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">
        <input type="text" name="remarkList" class="layui-input remark" th:value="${orderProduct.remark}">
      </td>
      <td id="productCoun" contenteditable="true">
        <input id="productCount" type="text" name="countList" class="layui-input count" th:value="${orderProduct.count}">
      </td>
      <td id="normalPric" contenteditable="true">
        <input id="normalPrice" type="text" name="priceList" class="layui-input price" th:value="${orderProduct.price}">
      </td>
      <td id="totalPric" th:text="${orderProduct.price}*${orderProduct.count}">
        <input id="total" type="text" name="totalPriceList" class="layui-input price" th:text="${orderProduct.price}*${orderProduct.count}">
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="" class="EditBtn">Edit</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="delBtn redType">Del</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```